# How to use wireshark with X11 protocol with sudo ssh session

Tags: linux

I am connecting to a linux server, I can use wireshark with X11 protocol, but when I use '`sudo wireshark`', I get:

```
MobaXterm X11 proxy: Unsupported authorisation protocol
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display localhost:10.0
Could not connect to any X display.
```

Comment: Since the X session is running for your user, the `DISPLAY` environment variable is not set for root. You could try `sudo -E` to preserve your environment variables or set the `DISPLAY` variables manually. If that works, I'll post this as an answer.

Comment: @eike The message "could not connect to display localhost:10.0" suggests that `DISPLAY` is already set.

Comment: @eike sudo -E helps me, thank You, 
wireshark  appear on my screen with warning:

QStandardPaths: wrong ownership on runtime directory /run/user/1000, 1000 instead of 0
13:10:40.983     Main Warn QXcbConnection: XCB error: 145 (Unknown), sequence: 175, resource id: 0, major code: 139 (Unknown), minor code: 20

but it is working